# Create XL Dropdown using POI in PARTICULAR CELL other 1st row and 1st column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create drop down in excel using POI by using the below code. It creates drop down in A1 cell. but i want to create in a any cell. Drop down creation in below code is not associated to a particular cell.

```
        DataValidation dataValidation = null;
        DataValidationConstraint constraint = null;
        DataValidationHelper validationHelper = null;


        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("sheet1");

        validationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet1);
        CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 7, 0,0);
        constraint = validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"SELECT", "10", "20", "30"});
        dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
        sheet1.addValidationData(dataValidation);


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:/drop-down.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
```

Can somebody point me through the steps for the same.

Comment: You're using data validation which is like formatting.  You just apply it to the range you want.

Comment: Can you please throw more light with sample on this. I am not getting your point. I want to create a drop down dynamically on specific cells. Above code creates only in Cell-A1. There is no provision to specify the cell no.

Comment: I'll give you a hint and then a simple Google search will help you. `CellRangeAddressList`

Comment: Guess what. Above code itself creates the drop down properly. Biggest blunder is, there is no sign of a drop down when i open the excel. I need to manually select the cell only after i have an indication that there is a drop down. Aaaahh. Anyways - Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: That's the way `DataValidation` works.  If you want a drop down to always display you'll need to create a control which you can't do in POI.

Comment: @SenthilKumarSekar I was confused at why there is no dropdown. As you said it doesn't display until clicked on that column. you saved me some headache.